# Solving two inverse problems with same solution

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-analysis, inverse-problem

I've got two inverse problems,

$$A_1 ~ x = b_1 \qquad A_2 ~ x = b_2$$

So far I've been solving them independently using Tikhonov Regularization and getting two estimates for $x$. However in my case $x$ represents the same solution in both equations. Is it possible to do a 'simultaneous' solve? Ideally I would be finding the answer for

$$\min \left( \lVert A_1 x - b_1 \rVert^2 + \lVert A_2 x - b_2 \rVert^2 + \lVert\Gamma x\lVert^2 \right)$$

Where $\Gamma = \alpha ~ I$ and $I$ is the identity matrix as in Tikhonov Regularization (aka ridge regression). I suppose I could just take the average of both solutions, wondering if there is a more statistically powerful way of approaching this however.

Comment: What's the relative accuracy of the measurements in $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$?  You may need to scale  to adjust for this.  Are all the measurements independent?  Correlation can complicate things.

Comment: Right now it's all modeled so I know $b_1$ and $b_2$ perfectly, but in practice I will know $b_1$ with perhaps 10x more accuracy. However at this step I want to assume I know them both equally and that they are independent.

Comment: So what is your question here?  It's easy to solve the three term least squares problem you've given in your question.

Comment: Is it? If you explain in an answer I'll mark it correct. I just use basic routines like numpy's [least square solver](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) . I'm not from a CS background, so I could be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write your problem as

$\min \| Fm - g \|_{2}^{2}$

where

$F=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A_{1} \\
A_{2} \\
\alpha I \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

and

$g=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$

You can use whatever linear least squares solver you want to solve this problem.